# How to validate autonumbering in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I've made a running numbering function that autofills the numbers in every new row of my table.

In most cases, I want to limit editing for this field, though sometimes I would need to keep it editable.

I want to use Data Validation to check that each cell is following the number in the cell above it, and pop the Data Validation error message in case the cell content is different than the following number.

How can I do this?

Comment: Data validation only works when the user has selected the cell and then either changes the value or leaves the cell.  What you want is conditional formatting to turn the cell a different color as a way to let you quickly identify the cell is the wrong value.

Comment: Conditional formatting would alert the user and be the easiest way to accomplish this. But, if that's not what you're looking for, you're going to need VBA and `worksheet_change(byval target as range)` and then, maybe `cases`? Not sure how your numbering scheme looks.